# How can I hide the "External" tag when I receive an email from outside my organization in the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA)?

Tags: outlook.com, outlook-365

My organization uses Microsoft Outlook 365 (Microsoft Outlook web interface - OWA), and since recently I see some "External" tag for each email I receive that came from outside my organization

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a few [Reddit users](https://redd.it/oxxanl), the display of the "External" tag for each email that came from outside my organization  is controlled by the organization's admins.

User [fieroloki](https://www.reddit.com/user/fieroloki):

> You don't. It's controlled by the admin

Some additional information by  [crw2k](https://www.reddit.com/user/crw2k):

> Your tenant admins have enabled this as it is a new optional feature. It can’t be bypassed like the old transport rule method that put the external warning in the email but could be hidden by spammers using css.
>
> The new external tag is a tenant wide setting not per user and it only supports a maximum of 30 external sender domain names in the whitelist (less if long domain names)